# How to trace log Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Twitter requests and responses

Tags: asp.net-core

Having an issue with Twitter returning a 403 error during the first leg of the 3-legged OAuth authentication while using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Twitter.

I read that it should be possible to "hook the Backchannel property on the options and log the full response from Twitter."

How do I go about doing this?

My setup code for the AuthHandler is as follows:

```
.AddTwitter(options => {
                options.ConsumerKey = "PRIVATE";
                options.ConsumerSecret = "PRIVATE";
                options.RetrieveUserDetails = true;
                options.SaveTokens = true;
})
```

There is a `HttpClient BackChannel` and other properties of the `TwitterOptions` class. How do I use this to log all requests and responses using it?

```
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Used to communicate with the remote identity provider.
    public HttpClient Backchannel { get; set; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     The HttpMessageHandler used to communicate with remote identity provider. This
    //     cannot be set at the same time as BackchannelCertificateValidator unless the
    //     value can be downcast to a WebRequestHandler.
    public HttpMessageHandler BackchannelHttpHandler { get; set; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets or sets timeout value in milliseconds for back channel communications with
    //     the remote identity provider.
    //
    // Value:
    //     The back channel timeout.
    public TimeSpan BackchannelTimeout { get; set; }
    //
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the twitter extension method contains TwitterEvents which is used to add some custom logic which will be raised as the bearer token is processed.

I suggest you could try to use it as below:

```
.AddTwitter(options => 
            options.Events = new TwitterEvents() { 
             OnCreatingTicket = async ctx => {
                //write some codes to log the response
             },
             OnRedirectToAuthorizationEndpoint = ctx => {
                 //write some codes to log the response

             }


            }
            
            )
```

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply - yeah I've looked into these events, the problem was there wasn't one which was called before/during the first leg of the OAuth flow which was where I was receiving the 403 from Twitter. It turns out I had to fix a lot of issues with forwarded headers and the applications PathBase but I have it working now. What I needed to see was what was the exact request being passed to Twitter was after it was being modified by the middleware. Couldn't figure out how to do that given that wireshark wasn't really an option (cause of HTTPS).